# convert array of hashes to csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, jruby

How do you convert an array of hashes to a .csv file?

I have tried

```
    CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") do |csv|
      @data.to_csv
    end
```

but it is blank

Comment: You have a variable (`csv`)  which is set, but never referenced. This often is (as in your case) an indicator for an error.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  @data.each do |hash|
    csv << hash.values
  end
end
```

If you want the first line of the CSV to contain the keys of the hash (a header row), simply do:

```
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << @data.first.keys # adds the attributes name on the first line
  @data.each do |hash|
    csv << hash.values
  end
end
```

---

Please read the comment of @cgenco below: He wrote a monkey patch for the Array class.

Comment: this works however i want to have the keys as well and this lists only the values

Comment: How do you want it? Have you seen my second part of code? Can you post an example of the data you have in your arrays of Hashes and how you want it to be in the csv please? @SamanthaKlonaris

Comment: Also, you can try directly `csv << @data.to_csv` inside the open do block.

Comment: When I add that line I get NoMethodError for "csv << @data.first.keys.to_s"

Comment: I wrote a monkeypatch based on this code so you can just call `array.to_csv(csv_filename)`: https://gist.github.com/christiangenco/8acebde2025bf0891987

Comment: Why `"wb"` shouldn't be `"wt"`?

Comment: This works fine if you're sure **all rows have the values in the same order** and **have all the same keys**. For a safer solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 9):

`CSV` is smart enough to deal with the non-uniform hashes for you.  See the code for [CSV::Writer#<<](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Writer.html#method-i-3C-3C)

So, this works, and is a bit simpler than the above examples:

```rb
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb", {headers: @data.first.keys} ) do |csv|
  @data.each do |hash|
    csv << hash
  end
end
```

Comment: Upvoted than realized, this is not generating headers for some reason

Comment: The `headers:` option just lets you use `<< hash` instead of `<< hash.values`. You still need `csv << @data.first.keys` if you want to include a header row.

Comment: Just use the `write_headers: true` option to write headers, no special writing necessary.

Answer (score 7):

If the keys are not the same in all rows, the current answers fail. This is the **safest** approach:

```
data = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {b: 3, c: 4}]

CSV.open("data.csv", "w") { |csv|
  headers = data.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
  csv << headers
  data.each { |row|
    csv << row.values_at(*headers)
  }
}
```

All keys will be present in the CSV, even if they don't appear in the first row:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |
|  | 3 | 4 |

Comment: for my array of hashes I did `data.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq`

Comment: `map(&:keys).flatten` and `flat_map(&:keys)` do the same thing, but the later is more performant.

Answer (score 5):

If the hashes aren't uniform then you will end up with data in the wrong columns. You should use values_at instead:

```
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  keys = @data.first.keys
  csv << keys
  @data.each do |hash|
    csv << hash.values_at(*keys)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me for one reason or another, so I'll throw in my contribution as well. Here's what worked for me for my array of hashes with ruby 2.7:

```
headers = data.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb", {headers: headers} ) do |csv|
  csv << headers

  data.each do |hash|
    csv << hash
  end
end
```